# git stuck during push operation

Tags: git, github, push

I'm trying to push to a repository for the first time. I'm using `$ git push -u origin master`. This is what happens:

```
Counting objects: 12654, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11481/11481), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12654/12654), 437.53 MiB | 16.41 MiB/s, done.
Total 12654 (delta 1477), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

And then nothing, the process seems stuck. I've tried this `git config --global http.postBuffer 5242880001` to no avail.

Reply to the comment: I'm not using proxies, I'm using https and github on a Windows 8. It does happen everytime.

Comment: so how's your network? any proxies? which protocol? using github? what's your operating system? git version? does it happen every time? on every repo? you'll need to provide more information to answer this.

Comment: also, since this is your first push, 437M push seems like a large one. Can you describe the contents of your repo? Does it work with a smaller one?

Comment: try to run "git gc" and then try to push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are pushing to GitHub, it has strict limit on [repo/file size limitation](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/), so check if those 437MB include some large files ([`git lfs` might help](https://git-lfs.github.com/) then).

Try and split that push into several pushes, pushing older commits first, then newer ones.

Comment: though if the limits would kick in, you'd see a message about it, not git getting stuck, right?

Comment: @eis I agree, but I would still check and test if splitting the push is a workaround.